# How do you get the remainder of a decimal in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, arithmetic-expressions

I'm looking at Racket as a friendly introduction to lisp, but I'm missing something. I need to simplify angles, so all I need to do get n mod 360. The problem is n may be a decimal. I looked through the documentation, but ["remainder"](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=remainder#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._remainder%29%29) and ["modulo"](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._modulo%29%29) both expect integers.

The [flonum module](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/flonums.html) looked promising, but doesn't look like it has a % function.

I ended up reimplementing it as this expression, which works well enough:

```
(define (float-modulo n m)
  (- n (* (floor (/ n m)) m)))
```

But I'd rather not do that if this is already supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket provides the R6RS division operators via the `rnrs/base-6` library, so you can do:

```
(require rnrs/base-6)
(mod 370.25 360)
> 10.25
```